# Deploying SQL Server database with dbup on Docker

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, docker-compose, dbup

At our company we use a couple methods of updating database models. we use sqlproj and dacpacs as well as we have a .net core app using DbUp. I have successfully containerized using dacpac based of this article [automating-sql-server-2019-docker-deployments](https://www.wintellect.com/automating-sql-server-2019-docker-deployments/)

Now I am working on Db Up. There are a few challenges that I've tried to sort out but I am not able to sort through them.

1. My first though was to gen a dockerfile based off mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest then install the .net core runtime and run the built dbup inside sql container. It has been hard to get the .net core runtime running I just can't seem to get it to work.
2. I was trying to use docker-compose to buildjust a norm sql db and also run the dbUp using a base image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build  and connect to the sql db this way. this is also not working
   here is my docker-compose.yml file(sorry for some reason i can't coy the code correctly here:

version: "3.7" services:   ms-sql-server:
image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ports:
- "1477:1433"
environment:
SA_PASSWORD: "SuperFun!23"
ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"   dbup-exe:
build: .
depends_on:
- ms-sql-server

[image]

In my Dockerfile I am calling the db but it won't connect to it

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["/Sentinel.DbUp.csproj", "Sentinel.DbUp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Sentinel.DbUp/Sentinel.DbUp.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/Sentinel.DbUp"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "Sentinel.DbUp.csproj" -c Release -o /app
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sentinel.DbUp.csproj" -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet run Sentinel.DbUp --ConnectionString=Server=ms-sql-server,1477;Database=Sentinel_Local;User Id=sa;Password=SuperFun!23; --WithSeedOnce --EnsureDatabase --PerformUpgrade
```

I have two errors

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
> instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible
>
> /bin/sh: 1: User: not found /bin/sh: 1: --WithSeedOnce: not found

Based on my research, I though when using docker compose between docker images you can reference ms-sql-server instead of local host.
also when executing the last command how do I append multiple arguments? it seems --WithSeedOnce is not considered and argument for the app

Comment: "we use sqlproj and dacpacs as well as we have a .net core app using DbUp" - have you considered simplifying to use a single method?

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I gather, there are two things that jump off the page:

- In a dockerfile, RUN  instructions are executed when the image is built. Entrypoint or command instructions are executed when the container is started. As such, the command to start the DbUp (which I assume is the last line in your current dockerfile) should be changed from RUN to entrypoint.
- using the depends on instruction does not mean that the docker will wait for your database to be ready before starting the DbUp container. It just means that the database container will be launch before your DbUp is launched. Instead you have to wait for the DB in you code or using a wrapper script like wait-for-it. Check the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer this make sense. I found this script to wait. "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh" the problem is that I think the server is up but not ready yet. when I do a docker-compose up --build after deleting the existing containers and images it fails "dbup-exe_1       | Could not connect to the database directly
dbup-exe_1       | System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'."  but if I run that again since the containers are ready it works